# Ajax Post to website and click button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, button

I'm new to AJAX, and I've been having trouble getting and posting to a website without using window.open(""). What I'm trying to do is click a button with an class name of "ClickHere" on a website without opening it using JavaScript/Ajax/JQuery. After "ClickHere" is clicked, 250 milliseconds later, a button called "ClickHere2" is created, and that needs to be clicked as well. Here is what I have so far (unsuccessful):

```
$.post("http://www.ExampleSite.com/TestButton", function(data) {
    $(".ClickHere")[0].click();
    setTimeout(function() { $(".ClickHere2")[0].click(); }, 275);
});
```

The inside of the function itself works when I'm on the page, but it doesn't work when I'm not on it. It doesn't post the function to the site, or it does but the $("ClickHere") parts fire on the current page instead of the one posted to.

Comment: Lookslike a typo `$.(".ClickHere")[0].click();` change to `$(".ClickHere")[0].click();` and `$.(".ClickHere2")[0].click()` to `$(".ClickHere2")[0].click()`

Comment: Thanks. Should it work now that that's been done?

Comment: Try it, nothing else seems to be problematic

Comment: It works if I have the page open and I run everything besides the post, but it doesn't work if I have a different page open and try everything.

Comment: Basically, the problem is that either the post does not work or the selectors select things on the page it is run from instead of the page posted to.

Comment: Is this happening across two different domains? ````example.com```` and ````exampleSite.com```` being different

Comment: This is happening on the same domain. Basically what I've determined my problem is is that the post works correctly, but the selectors that click fire on the page it is run from, instead of the page it posts to. Is there any way to make them fire on the page it posts to instead?

Comment: The ideal way to do this would be to make your server-side script that handles the POST print some new javascript to be executed on the new page. If its on the same domain the only way I can think of to run query selectors would be from loading the second page in an iframe, then you can run javascript on it as long as it's the same domain. I can give example code if that's acceptable. Otherwise, we'd have to do this with server side javascript, for example node and cheerio

Comment: ````$.post()```` is ideal for when you want to submit data to your server but do not want to navigate to a new page. So you can get JSON data from a post response and work with that, but traversing the dom with query selectors will be challenging.